# Animated Text Change

Tags: android, textview

Is it possible to animate a change in `TextView`'s actual text content an Android? If yes, how would one do this? Links to offsite resources also appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544969/android-opengles-animated-text-logic this post might be help full also this link dealing with some effects using android views http://www.hascode.com/2010/09/playing-around-with-the-android-animation-framework/#Combined_animation

Comment: Maybe this link helps you https://www.androidtutorialonline.com/animation-effects-to-text/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will tell you step by step. This is for the fade-in animation.

1. Create an XML file in the `anim` folder in resources by any name. Code of XML is below:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <alpha
           android:fromAlpha="0.0"
           android:toAlpha="1.0"
           android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
           android:duration="1600"
           android:repeatCount="0" />
   </set>
   ```
2. Create the object `Animation animation;` globally
3. Load the animation

   ```
   animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
   ```
4. Set the animation on `TextView`

   ```
   tv.startAnimation(animation);
   ```

By this way you can use any type of animation.

Comment: I don't understand, how to change one string to another.